# Why do I need to click twice for the link to load the dialog in Blazor href

Tags: blazor

Here is the code I am using and it works, just need to click the link 2x

```
<th>Name (<a href="" @onclick="@(() => OpenDialog("KnownPeople",sessionId, @pr.KnownPersonId))" @onclick:preventDefault>@pr.RecordChangeCount.ToString()</a>)</th>
```

Comment: This should not normally happen. It might be caused by othger elements (JavaScript) on your page.

Comment: Try to reproduce this with a [mre]. You have to eliminate the other potential causes.

Comment: Check this solution: use ><span> instead of <a> and remove @onclick:preventDefault